# An animal riddle

Tags: animals

> I eat fish
>
> I am native to India
>
> I can weigh over 200 kilos
>
> I also eat larvae

What am I?

Comment: Should this have a knowledge tag?

Comment: This is not a riddle.

Comment: This looks like a trivia quiz question rather than a puzzle.

Comment: A really obese Indian guy ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

....I am a..............

> [Gharial](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gharial)